# Gif loading image Owl Carousel LazyLoad in owl-lazy class?

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I want to set preloader image in owl carousel2. I have read the docs but i didn't find any information to use preloader image in lazyload plugin option.

here is the plugin website :

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

My Code :

```
<div class="single-product owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/0utRJ1mZoZg/1080x1350" data-fancybox="images">
    <img data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/0utRJ1mZoZg/600x600" class="img-fluid owl-lazy" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/aiNU4cA4UzQ/1080x1350" data-fancybox="images">
    <img data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/aiNU4cA4UzQ/600x600" class="img-fluid owl-lazy" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/295NLwGdrKM/1080x1350" data-fancybox="images">
    <img data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/295NLwGdrKM/600x600" class="img-fluid owl-lazy" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/NzsTFFB6Ng8/1080x1350" data-fancybox="images">
    <img data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/NzsTFFB6Ng8/600x600" class="img-fluid owl-lazy" />
  </a>
</div>
```

```
$('.single-product').owlCarousel({
 loop : true,
 items : 1,
 nav : false,
 lazyLoad: true,
});
```

I need to give preloader gif image, for better UX.

Could you please help me?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a background image of a loader gif. Also, I've wrapped the OwlCarousel call inside `$(window).load()` so that it'll wait for the images to load before it's initiated while the loader will take care of any Flash Of Unstyled Content (FOUC)

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.single-product').owlCarousel({
    autoHeight: true,
    lazyLoad: true,
    items: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    nav: false,
    dots: true,
    loop: true,
  });
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel {
  height: 300px;
}

.owl-carousel {
  background: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/ajax-loader.gif") no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

<div class="single-product owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/0utRJ1mZoZg/1080x1350" data-fancybox="images">
    <img data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/0utRJ1mZoZg/600x600" class="img-fluid owl-lazy" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/aiNU4cA4UzQ/1080x1350" data-fancybox="images">
    <img data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/aiNU4cA4UzQ/600x600" class="img-fluid owl-lazy" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/295NLwGdrKM/1080x1350" data-fancybox="images">
    <img data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/295NLwGdrKM/600x600" class="img-fluid owl-lazy" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/NzsTFFB6Ng8/1080x1350" data-fancybox="images">
    <img data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/NzsTFFB6Ng8/600x600" class="img-fluid owl-lazy" />
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```